# Google Tag Manager - best practice for custom tracking script

Tags: google-tag-manager, conversion-tracking

I am preparing a custom tracking and want to handle it with the Google Tag Manager. I am creating a new container with two tags. For each tag I am selecting "Custom HTML" as code.

I have one script, which should be displayed on each page and is writing one hash in the local storage.

```
<script>
    (function () {
        // write something in the local storage
    })();
</script>
```

For this tag I select "Page View" as trigger, because it should displayed on each page.

The second script is tracking the conversion on the thank you page after some form.

```
<script>

    (function () {

        var data = {};
        data.conversionId = 'XXXXXX';
        conversion(data);

    })();

    function conversion(data) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.frameBorder = 0;
        iframe.width = 1;
        iframe.height = 1;
        iframe.name = "stlconv";
        iframe.scrolling = "no";
        iframe.allowtransparency = "true";
        iframe.vspace = "0";
        iframe.hspace = "0";
        iframe.marginwidth = "0";
        iframe.marginheight = "0";
        iframe.src = url;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }

</script>
```

What would you select here as trigger? How to manage on the best way the second script?

1. How should the owner of the page set the "conversionId", so I can get the value in my script?
2. How to make the trigger on the best way, so this script is fired only after the form in send?

Answer (score 1):

1. This question is too broad as there is no general "best way" to pass paramters from page to GTM's custom HTML tag in your context. You should come up with a solution that works for you. You have a few options here:

   - Make the conversionid readable directly by your custom HTML javascript e.g. by using global JS variable, cookies or local storage
   - Pass the conversionid to GTM using dataLayer and use the dataLayer variable in your custom HTML tag (you can reference dataLayer variables using double curly brackets e.g. {{example}} )
2. You can use GTM's built-in "Form Submission" trigger which allows you to check validation. There is plenty of tutorials on how to set it up so if you have problem with that eigther expand your question or open a new one. I can recommend following tutorial: [form-trigger-tutorial](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-engagement-with-google-tag-manager/#1-form-tracking-in-google-tag-manager)